# Why have so many Grunge artists died of suicide and drug related deaths?

Tags: rock

The Grunge genre seems plagued by tragedy, with a large number of the top performers having taken their own lives. Is there some sort of connection to explain why all of these artists of the same genre and with such similar roots all died so similarly (either by suicide or drug related or both)?

Examples that come to mind:

- [Kurt Cobain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_of_Kurt_Cobain) of Nirvana
- [Chris Cornell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Cornell#Connections_to_other_singers'_suicides) of Sound Garden and other bands
- [Chester Bennington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chester_Bennington#Death) of Linkin Park but who also sang for Stone Temple Pilots
- [Layne Staley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layne_Staley#Death) of Alice in Chains
- [Scott Weiland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Weiland#Death) of Stone Temple Pilots

[Here is an article](https://www.syracuse.com/celebrity-news/index.ssf/2017/05/chris_cornell_grunge_musicians_who_died.html) with an even more comprehensive list.

Answer (score 4):

No matter what the genre of music is, many artists commit suicide. I guess it goes back to the fact that any form of art can be a way to express feelings and hoping that someone understands it. And when someone has mental disorders such as depression, he/she may rely on the art that he/she creates even more. When no actual human can't makes you feel better, art can make you feel better (when words fail, music speaks right?)
But the problem is that you may reach a point that you learn that even that short term good feelings that you get by making art is not enough and you need more. The more you get into it the more you realize that more people can't understand you and that just hurts. And it may hurt so much that you think that it's better to end your life.